# Wordpress 404.php 301 redirect but exclude one directory

Tags: php, wordpress, http-status-code-404, redirect, http-status-code-301

I use the following code in `404.php` file, to redirect all 404 errors to home page

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: ".get_bloginfo('url'));
exit();
?>
```

Now, I want to exclude from this redirection a directory called `guest`
How can I do that?
Thank you!

Comment: what is `guest`, is it a post type? page? archive? category?

Comment: Is outside of wordpress. Is a directory

Comment: if so - you could do something like `if(!is_post_type_archive('guest')): //make your redirect; endif;`

Comment: well - you would still just use conditions. to see if `guest` is part of the url

Comment: with something like `strpos('/guest', $url)`

Comment: Thank you for your help, but is not working :(

Comment: I got the solution

Comment: basically what i suggested :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

```
$url = 'https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if (strpos($url,'guest') == false) {
       header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: ".get_bloginfo('url'));
    exit();
} else {
}
```